# standard naming convention for servlet package?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

what should be the standard naming convention of a package which contains a servlet class?
if my project name is "Employee" and I work in company "XYZ" , then what should come in this: 
                 com.xyz.employee.***_*_**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard naming convention (other than the name should be in lowercase). Choose what is the most logical to you.

Classes are typically arranged by technical and/or functional domain. So the servlet could be in a package

- `com.xyz.employee.web` (all the web-related stuff of the app), or
- `com.xyz.employee.salary` (all the salary-related stuff of the app), or
- `com.xyz.employee.web.salary` (all the salary-related stuff of the web technical domain), or
- `com.xyz.employee.salary.web` (all the web-related stuff of the salary-related functional domain).